# cannot detect wired or wireless cards

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I have just installed Windows XP into my PC, but it couldn’t connect to the network because it says: it cannot detect wired or wireless cards. I go to: device manager —> network adapters. I see 1394 net adapter is listed there with dark green color in the front. If I right click on this item and go to properties, it says: this device is enabled and working properly. I also check from the BIOS, it does say: 1394 net adapter is enabled!

Does anybody know why it cannot detect wired or wireless cards? I need this XP OS software for a reason. Please somebody help!

Comment: Did you install the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

1394 is a FireWire interface and not a networking interface. It is used mostly to connect camcorders and other FireWire capable devices.

Windows XP does not have drivers for too many hardwares out of the box. You have to install drivers for almost everything. To have your networking up and running you should start with the chipset driver:

- https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=NNRHR

Then install the drivers for wired networking:

- https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=CP9RY

For wireless you have to figure out what Wifi hardware your laptop has got. The 1525 were shipped with two different wireless interface. You can simply try to install both drivers; most of the time the installer will check fon an appropriate hardware.

- Dell wireless (Broadcom):
  https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=D7HGJ
- Intel wreless:
  https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=VNR6D

Comment: I have the BIOS A17 installed in the computer, which is the only driver needed for my computer based on the Dell website --- Dell inspiron 1525

Comment: 1394 is a FireWire adapter not a networking adapter as far as I know. It is used to connect camcorders and other FireWire capable devices. I can see a bunch of drivers on Dell's site (networking included): https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-1525/drivers

Comment: If so, any recommendation on which driver I should download for the networking part?

Comment: The wired network is working now --- I could ping any website from the cmd window. However, there are problems with the Internet explorer. I got error msg "Windows cannot connect to the Internet using HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP. This is probably caused by firewall settings on this computer. Check the firewall settings for the HTTP port(80), HTTPS port (443) and FTP port (21)." Then I went to the "Lan setting" and make sure the proxy server box has no checks and everything is blank / unchecked on the page. However, I still get that error message.

Comment: How do you connect to the internet? Directly (using PPPoE or something like that) or via a router? Did you already install any anti virus software?

Comment: Via Ethernet. I couldn't install Mcafee because I couldn't download it from Internet. Does this mean I have to reinstall XP in order to solve this problem?

Comment: I know that you are using Ethernet but what is on the other end of the network cable?  An ADSL/cable modem or a router with NAT and firewall or a router without NAT and firewall? The Windows XP has some service pack 
installed?

Comment: I only know it is a home internet (wifi) from a high speed Internet provider. I used a router to regenerate the eithernet from this original wifi in a downstair room. Then, the ethernet cable was connected to this regenerated ethernet via this device. The same device also generated a new wifi network from the original wifi provided by the high speed Internet provider (either comcast or XFINITY, etc.)

Comment: I am able to install the driver for the Dell wireless (Broadcom) but not the Intel wreless. However, Internet Explorer couldn't work under the wireless connection either.

Comment: OK, then you're behind some kind of firewall so most likely not some sort of malware/virus infection causing this issue. I think this is beyond your original problem and you should now open a new question regarding this IE6+WinXP internet access issue (and accept my answer :) ).