# Internet Explorer couldn't work in Windows XP in an old Dell PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-xp, firewall, internet-explorer-8

I just installed windows XP into my old dell computer. After a lot of debugging ([cannot detect wired or wireless cards](https://superuser.com/questions/1340346/cannot-detect-wired-or-wireless-cards/1340400?noredirect=1#comment2008292_1340400)), I could finally ping any website from the cmd window. However, there are problems with the Internet explorer. I got error msg "Windows cannot connect to the Internet using HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP. This is probably caused by firewall settings on this computer. Check the firewall settings for the HTTP port(80), HTTPS port (443) and FTP port (21)." Then I went to the "Lan Setting" and make sure the proxy server box has no checks and everything is blank / unchecked on the page. However, I still get that error message.

Any help would be appreciated on solving this problem.

Comment: Did you install XP SP3?

Comment: Yes. If you take a look at the link of the original problem (https://superuser.com/questions/1340346/cannot-detect-wired-or-wireless-cards/1340400?noredirect=1#comment2008292_1340400), you can get a much better idea on what this problem is. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try disabling the windows firewall, does it work now? Make and specific model of PC? I assume all drivers are installed.

Comment: OK. I found the place to disable the firewall. However, the IE could only partially work now --- google.com is working, but yahoo.com couldn't work

Comment: IE with XP does not support many modern cryptographic solutions. According to SSLLabs tests (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yahoo.com&s=72.30.35.9&hideResults=on&latest) yahoo.com won't be able to negotiate a connection with IE+XP. If you really want to (safely) browse the internet then you better install Chrome or Firefox.